# ETag delay when using Rails stale? helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, etag

I'm trying to cache a menu on my page that is being called and rendered on every page of the application.  I'd like the server to return a new menu only if the user is stale (I update the user object when the user accesses a different part of the site)

The Javascript call to get the menu is:

```
$.ajax({
         url: slideMenuPath,
         method: 'get',
         cache: true,
         ifModified: true,
         success: function(response) {
           $('#left-nav-container').html(response);
         }
       });
```

And the Server-side code is as follows:

```
def index
  latest_user = User.find(session.user_id)

  if stale?(etag: latest_user, last_modified: latest_user.updated_at)
    @menu_info = Menu.new(latest_user)
    render partial: 'navigation/menus/slide_out', layout: false
  end
end
```

What I am seeing happening is a bit bizarre.  The first time the user accesses the site it loads the menu via Menu.new() (expected), and then every page that is hit it does not do the Menu.new() (again expected) and renders the cached version of the menu in the browser.

The problem I am seeing though is that when the User object is updated, the Menu.new is then called as expected, but then every page load after that calls the Menu.new for a minute or so and then starts caching the response.

The behaviour almost acts like the last_modified and updated_at comparison doesn't account for seconds and makes sure the updated_at is < last_modified and not <=, with the timestamp being in minutes.

What's even more confusing is that I am always getting a 200 back, not a 304 on the cached responses.

Bottom line is that the site is working, but the caching isn't really working for a minute or so after the User object is updated.  Any help would be appreciated!

Additional details:

Here is the raw request:

GET /ben_admin/menus/slide_out?current_url=%2Fben_admin%2Fwork_status_events%2Flist HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:3000
Connection: keep-alive
sec-ch-ua: " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="96", "Google Chrome";v="96"
Accept: */*
X-CSRF-Token: CtWkubye++oI7AU3xSjSeD2Z4mmRO9jC74kKhzT2evA2jwmD+Z578+4b2778/rRpex/hHqIZIlGha9XY/FQ0Rg==
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.110 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
sec-ch-ua-platform: "macOS"
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Referer: http://localhost:3000/ben_admin/work_status_events/list
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,es;q=0.8
Cookie: external_logon_page=; _session_id=6c6f1228d24a863228d1e3275c16888a; _device_id=LzhmZGtDZ0NBNGc4Y0ZlTmhMenhTby9sQWFzd3pibVJIUTBYS0c4UWtTSTBjNSt6L2k3OW1DU1BXUC8yQWlZdS9GRGNsTUMwaUVCcW1wVHQzMmZ6NGI0M3RVUGtnL01rZ0RWV2FqQys1aE09LS1lcFBkdzhldUh6aVVNT242QVpmTXpnPT0%3D--12816efa203b8f8788844830a6c9589f0f2add1a
If-None-Match: W/"709672ed9c25fd368b4ab51f83a2a690"
If-Modified-Since: Mon, 03 Jan 2022 16:31:21 GMT

Here is the response: (with a 200)

Cache-Control: max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Security-Policy: default-src http: ws: 'self' http://0.0.0.0:8080 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' http://0.0.0.0:8080 'unsafe-inline'
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
ETag: W/"960d12d5161594dcb1572e39e797b38b"
Last-Modified: Mon, 03 Jan 2022 19:12:13 GMT
Referrer-Policy: origin-when-cross-origin, strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Set-Cookie: _device_id=; path=/; expires=Fri, 03 Jan 2042 19:29:57 GMT; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Download-Options: noopen
X-Frame-Options: ALLOWALL
X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies: none
X-Request-Id: 88100f73-c264-45a6-a42a-1b0fde01bf12
X-Runtime: 5.397817
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block

Comment: Can you post the request and response headers for one of the requests where you didn't get the `Not Modified` response you were expecting?

Comment: @KevinChristopherHenry, thanks, I've posted the headers in the update.

Comment: The `ETag` in the response is different from the `If-None-Match` in the request, which explains why you get a full `200` response. If you look at the series of requests and responses you should be able to see when the `ETag` changes, and confirm that the caching aspect works (that is, that the browser always includes the latest `ETag` in its `If-None-Match`).